# What's up with [evernote] and [evernote-app-notebook]

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [evernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evernote) and [evernote-app-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evernote-app-notebook) be the merged?

Comment: For one, the tag excerpt on evernote-app-notebook seems to redirect people to the French version of Evernote's site... If we're not going to merge that certainly should be adjusted.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yea i found that strange.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: It was added by someone who doesn't appear to have any experience working with Evernote (at least, judging by the fact that they haven't answered any Evernote questions on the site yet are suggesting an edit to an Evernote-related tag wiki...). It seems they just added an excerpt to the tag for the sake of having one. I'm not even sure they speak French.

Answer (score 6):

Did some digging, the Evernote App Notebook seems to refer to a feature documented [here](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/app_notebook.php) to limit your app to only be able to use one single *app notebook*, instead of all notebooks.

I've put in a suggestion for a new tag wiki and excerpt, since the existing one didn't specify that, and linked to the French site.

A quick scroll to the questions showed 2 questions that certainly were specific to this feature, and more less specific (or plain off-topic) ones, but the tag might still be sensible for less specific questions to indicate that the developer wants to only use features that are allowed with the limited permissions that come with this feature.

Comment: I haven't worked with the Evernote API in many years, so having a dedicated feature that actually restricts client apps to a single notebook is new to me - and one I certainly would have used for the app I was building at the time. Back then I would simply have created a new notebook and used it as normal, just with the ability to read and write the rest.